# Should I pass a CancellationToken to Task.Run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, cancellation-token

Regarding this example:

```
return Task.Run(
   async () => {
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
       await Task.Delay(1000);
      }
    }, stoppingToken);
```

Should I pass the `stoppingToken` to `Task.Run` or not? How does this changes the code behavior?

Comment: As a side note you may wanna throw instead, to mark the task as cancelled and stop continuations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation but that depends on your usecase.

Comment: As a side note, if you want the `CancellationToken` to have stopping semantics (as it's evident from the name chosen for the variable `stoppingToken`), you should handle and suppress all `OperationCanceledException`s that may occur. By adding the `stoppingToken` as argument to `Task.Run`, you have one more point to watch for this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the task is scheduled to run but has not started yet, passing the token will prevent the task from being started if a cancellation is requested before the task is actually started.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

> A cancellation token that can be used to cancel the work if it has not yet started.

Do mind in your example you could pass the token to `Task.Delay` as well to minimize the time taken to respond to the cancellation request.